# Merging sorted pairs

Tags: matlab, numpy, octave

I have two (or more but if solved for two, it's solved for any number) 2-by-N matrices which represent points with an x (the first row) and y (the second row) coordinates. The points are always sorted in the increasing x coordinate. What I want to do is I want to merge these two matrices into one 3-by-N matrix so that if two points (one from each matrix) have the same x coordinate, they would form one column in the new matrix, the first row being the x coordinate and the second and third row being the two y coordinates. However, if there is a point in one matrix that has x coordinate different than all other points in the second matrix, I still want to have full 3-element column that is placed such that the x coordinates are still sorted and the missing value from the other matrix is replaced by the nearest value with lower x coordinate (or NaN if there is none).

Better to explain by example.

First matrix:

```
1  3  5  7  % x coordinate
1  2  3  4  % y coordinate
```

Second matrix:

```
2  3  4  7  8  % x coordinate
5  6  7  8  9  % y coordinate
```

Desired result:

```
1    2  3  4  5  7  8  % x coordinate
1    1  2  2  3  4  4  % y coordinate from first matrix
NaN  5  6  7  7  8  9  % y coordinate from second matrix
```

My question is, how can I do it **effectively** in matlab/octave and numpy? (Effectively because I can always do it "manually" with loops but that doesn't seem right.)

Comment: why isn't there a NaN in your desired result row 2, column 2?

Comment: @Andy because "missing value [is] **replaced by the nearest value with lower x coordinate** or NaN if there is none" - in this case the value for x == 1 which is present in the first matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `interp1` and the keyword `'previous'` for strategy (you can also choose `'nearest'` if you do not care if it is larger or smaller) and `'extrap'` for allowing extrapolation.

Define the matrices

```
a=[...
1  3  5  7;... 
1  2  3  4];

b=[...
2  3  4  7  8;...
5  6  7  8  9];
```

Then find the interpolation points

```
x = unique([a(1,:),b(1,:)]);
```

And interpolate

```
[x ; interp1(a(1,:),a(2,:),x,'previous','extrap') ; interp1(b(1,:),b(2,:),x,'previous','extrap') ]
```

**Timeit results:**

I tested the algorithms on

```
n = 1e6;
a = cumsum(randi(3,2,n),2);
b = cumsum(randi(2,2,n),2);
```

and got:

- Wolfie: 1.7473 s
- Flawr: 0.4927 s
- Mine: 0.2757 s

Comment: My first thought was `interp1`, definitely the better approach, I couldn't find the `'previous'` option when I had a quick flick through the docs

Comment: Great solution, thanks! Just one small issue - what if I really want to take the previous value and only if there is none then place NA? If I remove the ``'extrap'`` option, the value for ``b`` for the x value of 1 will be NA but so will be the value for ``a`` for the x value of 8. The ideal solution would be to have the value for ``a`` for (because there is a previous value) but not for ``b`` for 1 (because there is no previous value). But it is enough for me as it is, this would be just an icing on the cake.

Comment: I am not quite sure what the problem is. If I run the code, then it will return 1 for a and NaN for b. Don't you get `[1,2,3,4,5,7,8;1,1,2,2,3,4,4;NaN,5,6,7,7,8,9]`? if so, which number should be different?

Answer (score 2):

This verions uses set operations:

```matlab
a=[...
1  3  5  7;... 
1  2  3  4];

b=[...
2  3  4  7  8;...
5  6  7  8  9];

% compute union of x coordinates
c = union(a(1,:),b(1,:));

% find indices of x of a and b coordinates in c
[~,~,ia] = intersect(a(1,:),c); 
[~,~,ib] = intersect(b(1,:),c);

% create output matrix
d = NaN(3,numel(c));
d(1,:) = c;
d(2,ia) = a(2,:);
d(3,ib) = b(2,:);

% fill NaNs
m = isnan(d);
m(:,1) = false;
i = find(m(:,[2:end,1])); %if you have multiple consecutive nans you have to repeat these two steps
d(m) = d(i);

disp(d);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLjsMgDLzzFXOpRCVUKe0@E/UX@gNVDwSIFimBKJDd7qW/nrVJ93UIscfj8RiiyfrdLYs@nne7naiAA/AIPDeUgvN9gR4ujRDtSrojRAJemCeo4WlNgVdmbmDiMM7ZYQ4@BsQOV4LiZH3Q2SVhcFxLUstK1VvVlt@29HY@WNDnjUtrKx0amtD2rwpxYMT5pm7K6wsp@pDdlJzJ36pm2@BOaP8T2h9CcTs5EkScM5nGoPPkr8JSw0mf5EGFeXC9NGzPlj6qGI73NJgTTVFdqgeaxEh7R8o6fc9CSQxsIQUdpKXSIGtVMbfTfXKN8BzS2pIL533tglXVhYZi4zt8xhlv9FYY5j77sXd0E4FWmbMnkDTTLyVHTG6klZDfXKL8IyJlNyYyOPBEKz17sz6NbGVZvgA)

Answer (score 1):

Your example:

```
a = [1 3 5 7; 1 2 3 4];
b = [2 3 4 7 8; 5 6 7 8 9];
```

```matlab
% Get the combined (unique, sorted) `x` coordinates 
output(1,:) = unique([a(1,:), b(1,:)]);
% Initialise y values to NaN
output(2:3, :) = NaN;   
% Add x coords from `a` and `b`
output(2, ismember(output(1,:),a(1,:))) = a(2,:);
output(3, ismember(output(1,:),b(1,:))) = b(2,:);
% Replace NaNs in columns `2:end` with the previous value. 
% A simple loop has the advantage of capturing multiple consecutive NaNs.
for ii = 2:size(output,2)
    colNaN = isnan(output(:, ii));
    output(colNaN, ii) = output(colNaN, ii-1);
end
```

---

If you have more than 2 matrices (as suggested in your question) then I'd advise

- Store them in a cell array, and loop over them to do the calls to `ismember`, instead of having one code line per matrix hardcoded.
- The NaN replacement loop is already vectorised for any number of rows.

This is the generic solution for any number of matrices, demonstrated with `a` and `b`:

```
mats = {a, b};
cmats = horzcat(mats);
output(1, :) = unique(cmats(1,:));
output(2:numel(mats)+1, :) = NaN;
for ii = 1:size(mats)
    output(ii+1, ismember(output(1,:), mats{ii}(1,:))) = mats{ii}(2,:);
end
for ii = 2:size(output,2)
    colNaN = isnan(output(:,ii));
    output(colNaN, ii) = output(colNaN, ii-1);
end
```